# Not able to use Jenkins labels in pipelines

Tags: jenkins, label, jenkins-pipeline

I can't get Jenkins labels to work in Jenkins while using pipelines.

My node is defined with a label say "poolA", and the following pipeline should attempt to run on that node but it doesn't.

Any ideas why?

Console says:

```
MyAgentis reserved for jobs with matching label expression; Jenkins
is reserved for jobs with matching label expression
```

This is my pipeline:

```
node{
    label 'poolA'
    echo " jenkins pipeline for rapidx node" 
}
```

My node is defined as follows:

- Only build job with label expression ....
- Launch method : Java webstart
- Avail : Keep this agent online as much as possible
- Executors # : 1
- Other settings unchanged

Note that I am behind a firewall (no internet access during execution) using 
Jenkins 2.73.2

This is a clean install of jenkins on windows, the only change I made was to enable Java web start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following syntax for the pipeline:

```
node("poolA"){

    echo "Jenkins pipeline for rapidx node"

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the double quote helped on a clean install, but on my main instance I now have "(pending—master is offline)" - any clues?

Comment: added that new question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833618/jenkins-labels-getting-pending-master-is-offline-while-trying-to-execute-on