# jenkins & labels getting : pending—master is offline while trying to execute on non-master nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins instance where I am not able to use labels, builds are triggered but get stuck at "pending—master is offline". I have disabled the master (executor # : 0) as I do not wish to use it.

Instead I would expect the build to go to the next available node with the label mentioned in the pipeline.

```
node("mylabel"){
    echo " jenkins pipeline for mylabel nodes" 
 }
```

This works in a clean install of jenkins so I can only assume this is a configuration/compatibility issue on my master instance.

Could it be a permission issue?

more info about my master instance :

- I have used in the past the nodeLabel (with freestyle jobs) and have removed it (and removed all extra instructions in my jobs once removed via the management view).
- I am using the    Role-based Authorization Strategy and have defined roles for each projects in jenkins.
- Note that I am behind a firewall (no internet access during execution) using Jenkins 2.73.2

EDIT 1:
another syntax - same issue observed.

```
pipeline {
  agent{
         label "mylabel"
         echo " jenkins pipeline for mylabel node"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue occurred because I am not able to bypass the master node using the above pipeline. I understand that before the label selection there is a need for a default node to be available to run instructions.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: so I am making a guess really here as I can t get the pipelines to start anywhere without the master running. Having a hard time finding some documentation here.

Comment: The example I provided in the question is causing the issue. I've just tested with a slightly different approach and will add it - what am I missing?

Comment: `node("mylabel")` will definitely not execute on master (except you've changed its executor config / gave the master this label).

Comment: I agree, the concern here is that master node is needed for the labelled node to be called and do its job, and I was not aware of this need (I was initially going to leave the master down as unused). I've just tested on another instance and see the same behavior there now (master needs to be up). I have not read of such requirement anywhere hence the doubt and question here.

Comment: You mean to start the job? The Groovy DSL is executed in a so-called flyweight executor on the master. This does not block any of the executor slots (thus it can be 0), but the pipeline execution is supervised by the master. Parts of this (CPS) allow an agent to continue a job while the master restarts. But nothing works without the master in the Jenkins world. So don't shut it down. Probably too trivial to mention anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this is needed. I cannot agree with your comment "Probably to trivial to mention anywhere".

Comment: But how do you start the job at all or check the results when you shut down the master? This feels really weird..

Comment: Looking back at this issue, an example to explain where I'm coming from is teamcity - all teamcity agents are independents and no central or master agent is required to use agents.